# MySQL indexes not being used in large database

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have a very simple query on a large table (about 37 million rows).  This query takes over 10 mins to run and should be fast as the indexes are built correctly (I think). I do not understand why this query is taking so long.  I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction:

Query:

```
select type_id, sub_type_id, max(settlement_date_time) as max_dt 
from transaction_history group by type_id, sub_type_id
```

Create Statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE `transaction_history` (
 `transaction_history_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sub_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,     
 `settlement_date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_history_id`),     
 KEY `sub_type_id_idx` (`sub_type_id_id`),
 KEY `settlement_date` (`settlement_date_time`),
 KEY `type_sub_type` (`type_id`,`sub_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36832823 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Result from Explain:

```
id -> 1
select_type -> SIMPLE
table -> transaction_history
type -> index
possible_keys -> NULL
key -> type_sub_type
key_len -> 9
ref -> NULL
rows -> 37025337
filtered -> 100.00
Extra ->
```

Why is possible keys NULL?  It says it is using an index but it does not seem like it is.  why is ref NULL?  How can I make this query more efficient?  Is there something wrong with the indexes?  Do I have to change any values MySQL config file?

Thank you

Comment: I am not entirely sure how much an index can help with a query like that; while it probably helps grouping the values to be aggregated; you're still aggregating every value in the table (it does not know where in each group the max value is).  It _might_ help if the index where on `(type_id, sub_type_id, settlement_date_time)`; but I am not sure if MAX/MIN can take advantage of indexes, so that is a big _"might"_.

Comment: MAX/MIN can make use of a index @Uueerdo .. that index `(type_id, sub_type_id, settlement_date_time)` is a covering index for that query

Comment: Yes, a covering index will make it so the whole table does not need scanned, but will it make it so max does not have to scan every settlement_date_time? Edit: Ok, found some references that indicate MAX/MIN are handled smartly with indexes. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Thank you Uueerdo and Raymond for your input.  Unfortunately this did not work.  The query still takes too long to complete and the explain still shows the same results.  I'm going to try to repair the indexes just in case there is something wrong.

Comment: @user1783686 - Let's see the new `CREATE TABLE`, `EXPLAIN`, and the results that say it is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies to the two commenters who already gave the necessary `INDEX`; I'll try to say enough more to justify giving a 'Answer'.)

Use the 'composite' (and 'covering') index:

```
INDEX(type_id, sub_type_id, settlement_date_time)
```

There is no `WHERE`, so no need to worry about such columns.  First come the columns in the order listed in `GROUP BY`, then comes the other column.  The Optimizer will probably hop through the index very efficiently.

Why `NULL`?  Well the 2-column index is useless.  In general, if more than 20% of the table needs to be looked at, it is better to simply scan the table rather than bounce between the index BTree and the data BTree.

More tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql